# How to write for loop so that y_pr>=1 assign label 1 and y_pr<=-1 assign label -1?

Tags: python, for-loop

Given weights `w=[8, 10]` (1 by 2 vector) and `b=-5` for a hyperplane `w^Tx+b=0` and I want to use this hyperplane to classify the testing dataset `X_te` (51 by 2). For a data point `x_i`, the classification is based on if `w^Tx_i+b >= 1` then assigns the label `y=1` and if `w^Tx_i+b <= -1` then assign the label `y=-1`.

I try the following code:

```
def cla(X,w,b):
    pre_te=np.zeros(len(X))
    length=X.shape[0]

    for i in range(length):
        y_pred=np.dot(np.array(X[i]),w.T)+b
        if y_pred>=1:
            pre_te[i]=1
        else:
            pre_te[i]=-1
    return pre_te
```

I can assign `+1` to `y_pred` if `y_pred>=1`. How to add `-1` to `y_pred` if `y_pred<=-1` in the above for loop?

I do not think that write `else: pre_te[i]=-1` work... There will be 0 in the output...

Comment: switch the `else` for an `if` maybe?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh But there will be `0` in this for loop. Actually, the label is binary with `+1` or `-1`. Can we only assign binary labels?

Comment: you assigned zeroes everywhere at the beginning, so if some of your numbers are between `[-1, 1]`, then you will still have some zeroes in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [elif](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

```py
for i in range(length):
        y_pred=np.dot(np.array(X[i]),w.T)+b
        if y_pred>=1:
            pre_te[i]=1
        elif y_pred<=-1:
            pre_te[i]=-1
    return pre_te
```

Comment: But there will be `0` in this for loop. Actually, the label is binary with `+1` or `-1`. Can we only assign binary labels?

Comment: What do yoou need to happen when y_pred is 0 that is not clear from your question that  is - For a data point x_i, the classification is based on if w^Tx_i+b >= 1 then assigns the label y=1 and if w^Tx_i+b <= -1 then assign the label y=-1.